# Is there a way to directly access constants from a C header in a Swift program?

Tags: c, swift, integration

I've got a C-based program that includes a `.h` file full of domain-specific constants and enums; it looks something like this contrived example (just longer):

```
#ifndef MyProgramConstants_h
#define MyProgramConstants_h

#define MY_PROGRAM_NAME             "MyProgram"
#define MY_PROGRAM_PROTOCOL_VERSION 1.2345
#define MY_PROGRAM_TCP_PORT         33666

enum {
   SpecialConstantA = 0,  /**< speed of light */
   SpecialConstantB,      /**< speed of sound */
   SpecialConstantC,      /**< speed of thought */
   NumSpecialConstants    /**< guard value */
};

#endif
```

Meanwhile, there is a Swift/iOS application (not written by me) that checks out the above codebase as a git-submodule, and links to parts of it via Objective-C bridging.

This all works fine, my only gripe is that the Swift application has its own separate `.h` file that redeclares all of the same constants as above, using <del>Swift's</del> Objective-C's slightly different syntax, e.g.:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define PROGRAM_NAME             "MyProgram"
#define PROGRAM_PROTOCOL_VERSION 1.2345
#define PROGRAM_PORT             33666

typedef NS_ENUM(uint32_t, SpecialConstants) {
   SpecialConstantA = 0,  /**< speed of light */
   SpecialConstantB,      /**< speed of sound */
   SpecialConstantC,      /**< speed of thought */
   NumSpecialConstants    /**< guard value */
};
```

That works too, but now the constants are declared in two different locations, and anyone who updates the value of a constant in the C header has to also remember to update the corresponding constant in the <del>Swift</del>Objective-C header (and vice-versa), or else the constants will be inconsistent across languages and the behavior of the Swift program will be different from the behavior of the C code.

My question is, is there any way to get the Swift program to read this C header directly, as opposed to replicating it?  It looks like the `#define` syntax is identical in both languages, so I could presumably move at least those out to a separate cross-language `.h` file and `#import` them from a `.swift` file and `#include` them from my C header, but the `enums` looks a bit more tricky.

Comment: That second piece of code is Objective-C, not Swift.  Was that generated?

Comment: Ah, right.  (Shows how much I know about Swift, I guess.  :) ).  I presumed the file is hand-maintained; if it's machine-generated, it's not clear to me how (but if there is a way to machine-generate it from the C header, that would address my problem!)

Comment: Had another look: The second version has `SpecialConstants` which does not appear in the first code version.  This means that the second cannot have been generated from the first as it's shown now.  Is that just a matter of you missing something while copy-pasting it here?

Is that second file generated or not?

Comment: @meaning-matters as I mentioned at the top of the question, the posted code isn't a copy-paste at all; rather a contrived example showing the general nature of the two header files.  The actual code in question is proprietary so I can't post it here.  Based on your observations, I think the second file cannot be machine-generated, it must be hand-crafted.

Comment: If the second version is indeed not generated by Xcode but has been created manually, I'd try to use the C/first version and fix any issues that gives (with CPP macro tricks).  So what happens if you'd try that; what kind of errors does that give?